# What listener should I use? (Java)

Tags: java, swing, listener, jmenuitem

I want a listener that defines if a JMenuItem was selected. Not pressed, but just highlighted. I don't need MouseOver listener, because the selection is supposed to be performed from keyboard. What listener should I use? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried a FocusListener?

Comment: duplicate answering efforts (because OP obviously preferred re-posting instead of trying): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818689/i-want-to-perform-some-action-when-a-mouse-is-over-jmenuitem-what-listener-shoul

Comment: well, actually there is a difference between questions.

Comment: so what happened when you added a ChangeListener (as suggested in your other question)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess you add a ChangeListener to the ButtonModel of each JMenuItem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [addActionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener)).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616761/addmouselistener-or-addactionlistener-or-jbutton).

Comment: this answer is wrong: the requirement is to get notified on "not pressed, just highlighted" (OP using the term selected as synomym is unfortunate, though)